# Techniques for business process modeling

Tags: android-activity, process, uml, modeling

Can anyone suggest good diagrams/modeling techniques for business process modeling? I was thinking about using activity diagram but the process includes quite a lot of forks and secondly, activity digram may be somewhat difficult to understand to non-technical users.

Sequence diagram is rather similar but what other tools are there? DFD?

Answer (score 1):

For me UML activity or BPMN modelling would be the best way. 
Sequence diagram is more appropriate for sequence representation not flow specially with a lot of forks.

Comment: Agreed. I personally find activity diags cleaner than BPMN but that's personal choice.  They're semantically very similar just notationally a bit different.  As for forks: ADs handle forks & joins nicely so I wouldn't be concerned there.  (Probably the opposite - ADs provide a nice & intuitive way to show fork & join behaviour).  Finally notation: I've never had any issues using ADs with non-technical users.  People grok them intuitively pretty much without exception.  Readability depends more on what you write in the symbols than the symbols themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There are also the Eriksson-Penker UML extensions. [Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) supports these as well as BPMN; I don't know what sort of support other tools provide.